# Summation of a few elements in a text file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have got a text file which contains 14000 rows and 7 columns. I have to take each of this columns. Then I have to find the sum of 1st 40 elements, then the next 40 elements(41-80) then the next 40 (81-120) and so on. I have written a MATLAB code for this. It is:

```
clc;clear all;close all; 
fid = fopen('sks.txt');
datacell = textscan(fid,'%f%f%f%*[^\n]',...
'delimiter','\t');
fclose(fid); 
A = datacell{1};
B=datacell{2};
l=size(A);
k=40;
sum=0;
for x=1:k
    sum=sum+A(x);
end;
sum
for y=1:((l/k)-1)
 sum1=0;
    for i=((y*k)+1):((y+1)*k)
      sum1=sum1+A(i);
    end; 
end;
```

I am getting all the sets of sums correcly with this code but I want all the answers as a single matrix. That is presently all the answers are obtained seperately. There are 350 seperate answers. I want all 350 in a single matrix. I want something like

```
Sum=23
    34
    87
.......
```

and so on.

Not

```
 sum=23
sum=34
sum=87
```

I am not good at coding or MATLAB. So if there is a simpler way other than this you are more than welcome to give me that. Or please help me modify this code.:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign those values in such a way (matrix will expand with every iteration):

```
sum = [] % init output matrix
for y=1:((l/k)-1)
 sum1=0;
    for i=((y*k)+1):((y+1)*k)
      sum1=sum1+A(i);
    end; 
    sum = [sum; sum1]    % it will automatically expend matrix
end;
```

or as You know the final output of the Sum matrix (length(1:((l/k)-1)))

```
sum = zeros(1,length(1:((l/k)-1))) % init output matrix
ii = 1; % matrix index
for y=1:((l/k)-1)
 sum1=0;
    for i=((y*k)+1):((y+1)*k)
      sum1=sum1+A(i);
    end; 
    sum(ii) = sum1   % assign value to matrix
    ii = ii + 1;     % increment matrix index
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

*Not the whole answer* - but will make the code much cleaner and faster:

You might run into some problems as `sum` is actually the name of a built-in function - which *accidentally* does exactly what you do in loops (just quicker).

Use stuff like:

```
mySum = sum(A)
```

and

```
mySum1 = mySum1 + sum( ((y*k)+1):((y+1)*k) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers guys. I got a simpler way. So I thought I will share it here. There is a command called reshape in matlab so I used it like this

```
A = datacell{1};
A1=squeeze( sum( reshape(A, 40, [], 1) ) );
```

A1 will give the sum of each set of 40 elements.